# In prepared statement after SQLException on SQL Width in JAVA

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge, java-6

I have a problem with prepared statements in JDBC against an OpenEdge database, when we get the following exception:

> java.sql.SQLException: [DataDirect][OpenEdge JDBC Driver][OpenEdge] Column Namn in table PUB.Brevlada has value exceeding its max length or precision.

I'm well aware of the fix for this with DBTool but I have another question. When we have used the prepared statement and got this Exception it can't be used again to fetch other entries in the table that hasn't got the width problem. We then get a slightly different exception:

> java.sql.SQLException: [DataDirect][OpenEdge JDBC Driver][OpenEdge] Column %s in table %s has value exceeding its max length or precision (7864)

Is this a problem with the SQL Statement Cache on the server, and is there any workaround for this except for re-initialization of the JDBC connection to the database?

Comment: What is the version of OpenEdge?

Comment: I tried to this scenario with OpenEdge 11.6.3. I didn't get the second exception. I got the results as expected. Can you provide your sample code?